# My datetime field in models.py does not work even though it does not raise any exceptions while migrating

Tags: django, datetime, datefield

In my models.py **I have a field `created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)` which does not raise any problems while migrating** and such, however when I save a post, it gives me `ValueError at /admin/blog/post/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'14 21:27:46.098090'`

I have went through documention, and I tried doing input_format but I couldn't get it to work

I just want to be able to not have just the date saved, without the time.

**Or perhaps I just format it in the template to show day,month,year**. **But how do I do that?**

EDIT: Here's the view

```
    object_list = Post.published.all()
    paginator = Paginator(object_list, 3)  # 3 posts in each page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer deliver the first page
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range deliver last page of results
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    # posts = Post.published.all()
    return render(request,
                  'blog/post/list.html',
                  {'posts': posts})


class PostListView(ListView):
    queryset = Post.published.all()
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 3
    template_name = 'blog/post/list.html'
```

In the template I am doing a simple `{{post.created}}`

EDIT 2:
Exception location is Exception Location:

```
c:\users\jessa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py in convert_date, line 64
```

EDIT 3:

It also shows me the error is at line 12 of base.html which is...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'fonts/ionicons.min.css' %}">
```

EDIT 4:

Moreover, when I change the `DateField` to `DateTimeField`, suddenly everything renders without any problems

Comment: Please show the code where you are setting that value. But what is it? It doesn't seem to be a recognisable date format.

Comment: seems like somehow somewhere `datetime` value try to be converted into `int`. without the whole code its not possible to detect the cause of the problem.

Comment: Can you show the view or form from which this error comes? It should be easily solvable by pruning the time part from your input.

Comment: Code added. Take a look

Comment: @mfrackowiak - here's where it gets interesting. It's in base.html line 12 which is ```<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'fonts/ionicons.min.css' %}"> ```

Comment: @DanielRoseman I set the value right here - ```created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)```

Comment: @AleksanderJess : were you able to solve this issue? I have the same exact issue now